# How do I disambiguate relationship names in a salesforce subquery

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am attempting to do a nested query on an object that has two related lists that happen to have the same relationship name.  The query is always picking the related list associated with the standard object, but I want to query the list associated with the custom object.   Here is the query:   select ID, RecordType.Name, (select Id, Line_of_Business__c from Quotes) from Opportunity.   The relationship name Quotes is associated with both the standard Quote object, (API name Quote) and a custom object, (API name Quote__c. )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom relationship should be named `Quotes__r`, you sure you have a problem?

What do you see when you run a describe (see my answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/23507/799, pick the "go down" piece) or open the object in https://workbench.developerforce.com/ ?

Comment: Quotes_r would be a reference to a lookup relationship from something to Quotes.  In this case, quote__c is the object that is looking up to an opportunity, using the relationship name quotes, which you can see in the detail of the lookup field.   In querying from Opportunity to quote, you are supposed to use the relationship name, which is quotes in this case.

Comment: No. Looking "up" is not the only place where "__r" appears. All custom relations get an "__r" (and sometimes even managed package's prefix). It'd take you less time to try it out than to write this comment, give it a go.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm - skim through whole chapter in the sidebar, not just this particular page

Comment: Don't trust what you see in setup. You see "Quotes" but effective API name is `Quotes__r`. Or post a screenshot from workbench and I'll eat my words.

Comment: you can put your knife and fork away.  thanks for the lesson!